# Anypoint Enterprise Security IP Filter

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

Hi I am working with Mule Anypoint Studio and I am trying to implement a list of IP's but my program is allowing every request from all IP's and it works only for one request per browser. How it is working i have no Idea. Please elaborate the working . Please don't share Mule Documentation Link because there they have not given much information.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:filters="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/filters" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
 xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/filters http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/filters/current/mule-filters.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd">
    
    <filters:config name="Filters" doc:name="Filters"/>
    
    <flow name="mule-security-ipFlow1" doc:name="mule-security-ipFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="196.111.1.1" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP" path="ip"/>
        <filters:filter-by-ip config-ref="Filters" regex="196.16.4.1,196.17.7.13" doc:name="Filters"/>
        <set-payload value="#['Data Mast']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <logger message="#[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
    
</mule>
```

Comment: which version of Mule are you using?

Can not find the "filter-by-ip" filter in the last one (3.6.0).

However, if you move to 3.6 you could use a regex filter on the http.remote.address inbound property to filter out unwanted IPs.

HTH, Marcos

Answer (score 0):

there are two scenarios here, we can specify regular expression to allow certain ip range requests or we can specify single ip address as part regex attaribute value.

`<filters:filter-by-ip config-ref="Filters" regex="${fms.iprange}"
            doc:name="verify-ip-address" />`

if we want to allow comma separated  ip address, its better to write custom filter and do the required logic .

Comment: how to mention this fms.iprange and where i have to mention in the property file. Please tell the format

Comment: just specify the ip address in properties file eg: 111.11.11.11
or
if you want to specify the regular expression for the same property below is sample expression
(33|1)\\.(100|60)\\.(141|80)\\.[0-24]
its just a sample.
hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are intending to deploy your flow your other option is to use api-kit to apply the IP whitelist (or blacklist) to your flow as a policy:

[image]